# retrieve complex result using left join

Tags: mysql, sql

i have these 4 tables

```
1. course 
------------------------ 
CourseID   CourseNum    CourseName             

2. courseRequirements
------------------------
CourseID  ReqID                

3. semestercourses
------------------------
CourseID                

4. studentcoursecomplete
-----------------------
CourseID   StudentID
```

the statement must do the folowing

1-show the course name from table course where course.CourseID=semestercourses.CourseID
2-don't show the course that student complete "studentcoursecomplete"
3-don't show the course that have a requirement that student didn't finish 
4- show the course that have requirement that student finish

example

this semester there are 3 courses (english 2,math,sport)
john is a student
he complete the math course (studentcoursecomplete)
english 2 have a requirement "english 1"(courseRequirements)  and he didn't finish english1 (studentcoursecomplete) if he complete english 1 , english 2 will be shown
so he can see just "math" course

i have this statement

```
SELECT course.*
FROM course
LEFT JOIN studentcoursecomplete ON studentcoursecomplete.CourseID = course.CourseID
LEFT JOIN courseRequirements ON courseRequirements.CourseID = course.CourseID
WHERE courseRequirements.CourseID IS NULL
    AND studentcoursecomplete.CourseID IS NULL
```

this statement work fine but if the student finish english1 ,english2 didn't shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see that you're incorporating the courses that are currently announced for the given semester. With your database structure as a basis, the following query produces the desired effect that you have described.

```
SELECT c.* FROM semestercourses AS sc
    LEFT JOIN course AS c ON sc.CourseID = c.CourseID
    LEFT JOIN courserequirements AS cr ON cr.ReqID = c.CourseID
    LEFT JOIN studentcoursecomplete AS scc ON scc.CourseID = c.CourseID
WHERE 
    scc.CourseID IS NULL
```

While prerequisites aren't met but the course is announced, it won't be visible. If it's announced and prerequisits are met, and the upper tier course isn't completed yet, it is visible. Finishing 'English 1' in this example, if English 2 is announced (in `semestercourses`), then it will be visible for you.

**Edit:

```
SELECT c.* FROM semestercourses AS sc
    LEFT JOIN course AS c ON c.CourseID = sc.CourseID
    LEFT JOIN courserequirements AS cr ON cr.CourseID = sc.CourseID
    LEFT JOIN studentcoursecomplete AS scc ON scc.CourseID = sc.CourseID
WHERE 
    sc.CourseID NOT IN (SELECT CourseID FROM studentcoursecomplete)
        AND 
    (cr.ReqID IS NULL OR cr.ReqID IN (SELECT CourseID FROM studentcoursecomplete))
```

Alright, made some changes after running a few more tests with the data.

Comment: that's not work .. i put courses in semestercourses and i try this and didn't work correctly

Comment: yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeees maaaaaaaaaaaan ^_^ thaaaaaaaats work fine

Comment: thank's @Gabor but can u help me .. how can i select these records for specific student for example StudentID=1